# Details to setup Microsoft exchange works on iPhone but not on Samsung S6?

Tags: exchange, samsung-galaxy-s-6

I've tried to set up Microsoft Exchange on my new Samsung S6.  All the details used work on my old iPhone but will not work on the Samsung S6?

I've tried downloading Outlook and doing it from in there, but that won't work either. It says my server is not supported?

Comment: I considered that the details you said regarding iPhone were setup related and not use-case related, so I edited the title. Please do [edit] if the case is otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

There is very good step by step tutorial for configuring the exchange account in Samsung galaxy s6

Please look into the following URL and try to configure your mobile with the given example in the tutorial using your own credential

http://support.bell.ca/Mobility/Smartphones_and_mobile_internet/Samsung-Galaxy-S6.how_to_add_a_microsoft_exchange_email_account_on

And if it works please accept my answer and votes up :)